# How to open a modal in ionic 5?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I want to open a modal in ionic 5. But somehow I can't find the component.module.ts file where I can export the modals/componets that I want to use. Did they change that system, how is it done with ionic 5? Do you know a piece of documentation for that? The whole system seems to have changed like there is always a `page-routing.module.ts`. in every page file.

Comment: Share your code what have you tried? if you are getting any error also share it.
Check documentation Here:  https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing new changes for opening modal.

Add modalPage or modalComponent to app.module.ts  [ Or Home.module.ts if lazy-loaded ]  in `entryComponents and declarations`

## app.module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { FolderPageRoutingModule } from './folder-routing.module';
    import { FolderPage } from './folder.page';  //from where you open
    import { ModalPage } from '../modal/modal.page';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        IonicModule,
        FolderPageRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ModalPage], 
      entryComponents: [ModalPage]  //modal page
    })
    export class FolderPageModule {}
```

and open you modal from corresponding page.

```
 async presentModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: ModelComponent,
      componentProps: { value: 123 }
    });

    await modal.present();

  }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it